# Control Multiple WebViews From Inflated Layout

Tags: android, webview, tabs

I'm trying to make it so the user can add/delete tabs.
When a new tab is added, the tab's content is set to TBrowser.class.

Below is how the tabs are made:

```
private void addMethod() {
        ++i;

        Intent TBrowser = new Intent(); 
        TBrowser.setClass(this, TBrowser.class);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(Integer.toString(i)).setIndicator("Tab").setContent(TBrowser));
    }
```

TBrowser.class has the contentView of a layout with a WebView in it basically.

So far it works fine, except I can only control the WebView of the most recently created tab, (eg refresh, go back etc). So my question is how can I control all the WebViews? I've spent a pretty silly amount of time trying to get this to work so I really appreciate any help! Let me know if there's anything else you need me to supply.

(How I'm trying to find the webviews and refresh for example:)

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) TBrowser.mWebView;
mWebView.refresh();
```

I tried setting a tag to the webviews as they are made and finding the webview by tag but that only seemed to work for one and after that it would just go back to only working for the newly created one...

**--Edit --**

I have

```
private WebView webViews[]=new WebView[10];
private int p = 0;
```

Globally defined in the MainActivity now.
Below is called every time the add tab button is pressed.

```
private void addMethod() {
        ++i;

        Intent TBrowser = new Intent(); 
        TBrowser.setClass(this, TBrowser.class);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(Integer.toString(z)).setIndicator("z").setContent(TBrowser));

        ++z;

        test();   
    }
```

And below is called every time addMethod is called.

```
public void test(){
        webViews[p] = TBrowser.mWebView;
        p++;
    }
```

and I'm checking to see if it works by trying to reload it.. (which now only works in the first tab)

```
int cT = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
                        if (cT == 0){
                            if (webViews[0] != null){
                                webViews[0].reload();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (cT == 1){
                            if(webViews[1] != null){
                                webViews[1].reload();
                            }
                        }
```

**--    --**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In every tab you are using different WebView or single WebView for all Tabs ??

Comment: @sushildlh there's a layout with a webview, the layout is inflated every time a new tab is added. So, different webview for each tab.

Comment: what about your last webView . Will you stored it Or you point new WebView to the same WebView object ??

Comment: I think I just point the new WebView to the same object.

Comment: may be that is problem ........

Comment: @sushildlh I've never done that before.. Could you show how to do it and if it works I'll accept your answer? :)

Comment: i am not sure about all your work so it takes long time to create me Tap Applicartion .....have look on my answer you have some tips to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122492/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-tssomas).

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: @sushildlh nope :/

Comment: post your whole Activity code here ......

Comment: I've edited in some more detail for you

Comment: please read first Explicit intent and then tell me if you got some idea or not ?? ANd also have look on edit answer....